# How to append this dynamically generated html inside another one in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dynamically generated html in my jquery file like so:

```
var comm = '<div class="media" data-id='+user.id+'><div class="media-left"><div class="media-body"><div class="media-heading"><p><strong>'+user.title+'</strong></p><h5 class="name"><strong>'+user.name+'</strong> @ '+user.time+'</h5></div><div class="media-text"><p>'+user.body+'</p></div><div class=""><a class="reply_link">Reply</a></div><div class="reply_wrapper"></div></div></div></div><br/>';
```

and another one to be appended inside the .reply_wrapper in this var comm.

```
var reply = '<div class=”row”  id="rep"><div class="rep_body"><h4 class="rep-heading"><strong>'+user.name+'</strong></h4><h4>’+user.reply+’</h4></div></div>';
```

Boh variables are declared and bind inside a click event.
To capture the parent container where the second variable 'reply' will be appended:

```
var parent_cont = $(".media").attr("[data-id="+user_id+"]");
```

However, I tried appending the var 'reply'  inside 'comm' with this without success:

```
parent_cont.find(".reply_wrapper").append(reply);
```

Can somebody kindly guide me on the proper way to code this please.

Comment: jQuery's `attr` returns a **string** when used as a getter, so `parent_cont` is a **string**, it has no `find()` method

Comment: the `$(".media").attr("[data-id="+user_id+"]");` would return nothing as the `[]` are wrong when using the `attr` method. You most likely mean `$(".media").find("[data-id="+user_id+"]");`

Comment: Thanks @adeneo & Gaby. Several of these Var comm will be generated dynamically on the page, please how do I navigate the dom to correctly select the one with the targeted data-id. That's my challenge.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var parent_content = $('.media[data-id=1]');

parent_content.find('.reply_wrapper').append('Hi there');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media" data-id=1>
  <div class="media-left">
    <div class="media-body">
      <div class="media-heading">
        <p><strong>user 1</strong></p>
        <h5 class="name"><strong>user 1 name</strong> @ time</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="media-text">
        <p>description</p>
      </div>
      <div class=""><a class="reply_link">Reply</a></div>
      <div class="reply_wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><br/>
```

You are selecting your `parent_cont` incorrectly. What you need is:

```
var parent_cont = $('.media[data-id=' + user_id + ']')
```

This way, you selected your `parent_cont`. After this, `parent_cont.find(".reply_wrapper").append(reply);` should work